# Can the questioner with <3000 rep see his/her close votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

I would test it out here but I'm not sure if anyone has voted to close any of my questions.  I'm curious because it could result in quicker edits by the asker.

I suppose a follow-up question is -- *should* they be allowed to see that close votes are accumulating on their question?

Comment: Test! Which close vote have I picked?

Comment: Guess not...  Wonder what the thoughts are on the follow-up question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, I thought they are able to see the close votes to their questions, even if they have below 3K rep. That would help especially with dupe posts, if no-one mentioned it in a comment.
So, I vote to implement it.

**Edit:**
[John Rasch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44765/john-rasch) [pointed out correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26501/can-the-questioner-with-3000-rep-see-his-her-close-votes/26522#26522), that you only need 250 rep to vote to close your own questions. So I want to clarify, that I think you should be able to *see* the close votes/reasons, even if you are below that threshold.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone with 250 rep can "Vote to close or reopen your questions" according to the FAQ, which means they can also see the close votes.

Comment: Guess I don't have the rep to see that here.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to be over 3k rep to see your close votes.
It probably would be useful for a user to see the close/reopen votes on his questions.

I'll change this to a feature request for those interested.

Comment: I thought so too, but there's an exception for your own questions - which require 250 rep to vote to close/reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that we (since I'm <3k) not be able to see *who* voted to close, but the number of votes and reasons.

(Yes, it gets revealed once closed, but I think this would be good to avoid making newbies mad *at someone in particular*.)

Comment: Even over 3K you can't see the names of those who voted to close.

Comment: Oh.  *ahem*  Nevermind then.... move along, nothing to see here...